# Google Glass : OnCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, google-glass

I am trying to modify the title of menu item on google glass dynamically. 
As there is no hardware menu button and My activity is themed NoActionBarFullScreen,
creating and initializing the Menu menu item in onCreateOptionsMenu always give null value because onCreateOptionsMenu never called. So how to do that ?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gatt_services, menu);
    if (!init) {
// I want to do this outside of this function also
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect).setTitle("Connect");           }
 else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect).setTitle("Disconnect");
    }
// so I initialized this variable here
    this.menu = menu; // but this is always null
    return true;
}

MenuItem connetItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect); // App crashes
```

So how do i access this menu item and change its title?

Comment: Did you try [OnPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) ?

Comment: yes I do intialize "menu" there but its always null

Comment: We might need the full code of your activity. Do you use a Fragment ? Because the menu of a fragment could override the one of an activity.

Comment: I am not using fragments at all. I am just using a full screen activity and I have 4-5 menu items. I just want to change their(a menu item) title on a button click thats it.

Comment: Well post your whole Activity's code. It's weird that menu is null because then 
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gatt_services, menu); 
shouldn't work, and you would not be able to see the menu in the application.

Comment: I assume you're calling `openOptionsMenu();` to actually display the menu, as specified in https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/immersions#displaying_the_menu ?

Comment: yes i am calling that